# Calculate monthly profit/loss from stock options positions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I recently switched from Google Sheets to Excel where I had this feature and I've spent several hours studying various methods but, for the life of me can't figure out which formula would be best or how to write said formula in Excel.

I want to be able to calculate the amount of monthly income earned from specific options strategies in an Excel stock options portfolio spreadsheet onto a different sheet within the same workbook titled `Monthly Income`. For instance, one of the sheets in the workbook is titled `Calls` where I keep track of the `Covered Calls` I sell against stock positions. Within that sheet column `AE` is titled `Month Closed` where I document when a position is closed and the following column `AF` is titled `Actual Profit / Loss` where the profit or loss of each position is calculated.

During any given month there can be anywhere from no transactions, to several so these need to be tallied up in they meet criteria for that month.  So, the columns in the `Monthly Income` sheet carry the titles of `Income Type`, `Amount` and the numerical year such as 2023. Thanks in advance.

[image: Monthly Income sheet]

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the monthly income earned from specific options strategies in Excel, you can use a combination of functions like SUMIFS, MONTH, and YEAR. Here's how you can set up the formula:

Create a new sheet in the same workbook titled "Monthly Income" with columns "Income Type," "Amount," and the numerical year.

In the "Income Type" column, list the different options strategies you want to track.

In the "Amount" column, you can use the following formula to calculate the monthly income for each strategy:

```
=SUMIFS('Calls'!AF:AF, 'Calls'!AE:AE, ">="&DATE(year, month, 1), 'Calls'!AE:AE, "<="&EOMONTH(DATE(year, month, 1), 0))
```

Replace 'Calls' with the actual sheet name where you keep track of the Covered Calls (e.g., if your sheet name is "Calls"), and adjust the column references (AE:AE and AF:AF) if they differ.

Replace year and month with the numerical year and month you want to calculate the income for. For example, if you want to calculate income for May 2023, use 2023 for the year and 5 for the month.

Drag the formula down in the "Amount" column to calculate the income for each options strategy.
This formula uses the SUMIFS function to sum the values in the "Actual Profit / Loss" column ('Calls'!AF:AF) based on specific criteria. It checks the "Month Closed" column ('Calls'!AE:AE) for dates within the specified month and year using the DATE, YEAR, and MONTH functions.

Make sure to adjust the formula references ('Calls'!AF:AF and 'Calls'!AE:AE) to match your actual sheet and column references. You can replicate this formula for other sheets or options strategies by adjusting the sheet name and column references accordingly.

Remember to modify the formula if you have different sheets or column titles in your workbook.

Comment: First off, thanks so much for your response.  Your formula works perfectly and I'm very grateful.  For anyone else that might be interested here's the exact formula for May 2023.  =SUMIFS(Calls!AF:AF, Calls!AE:AE, ">="&DATE(2023, 3, 1), Calls!AE:AE, "<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2023, 3, 1), 0))